# Receive data from DB in sqlalchemy model, if I create a select query only with 2 of 6 columns (without unnecessary data from the remaining 4 column)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

In my Fastapi project I have a table model with 6 columns. I have tried to make query for returning data only from 2 columns:

```
query = select(PostSQL.id, PostSQL.title)
result = await db.execute(query)
post = result.all()
```

I have response with list of tuples: [(1, 'hello'), (2, 'hello')]

When I create a select query with:

```
query2 = select(PostSQL).options(load_only(PostSQL.id, PostSQL.title))

result2 = await db.execute(query2)
post2 = result2.all()
#or post2 = result2.scalars().all()
```

I have response data that converted to PostSQL object with data from all table columns.

ENDPOINT FUNCTION WITH DEBUUGER DATA:

```
@router.get("/custom1", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def get_custom_posts(db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_db), current_user=Depends(get_current_user)):
    query = select(PostSQL.id, PostSQL.title).order_by(PostSQL.id)
    query2 = select(PostSQL).options(load_only(PostSQL.id, PostSQL.title)).order_by(PostSQL.id)
    query3 = select(PostSQL)
   
    result = await db.execute(query)  # <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ChunkedIteratorResult object at 0x104c2b900>
    result2 = await db.execute(query2)  # <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ChunkedIteratorResult object at 0x104c3c580>
    result3 = await db.execute(query3)  # <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ChunkedIteratorResult object at 0x104c709c0>

    post = result.all() # [(1, 'helo'), (2, 'helo'), (3, 'helo')]
    post2 = result2.scalars().all() # [<app.models.PostSQL object at 0x104c33a90>, <app.models.PostSQL object at 0x104c33850>]
    post3 = result3.all() # [(<app.models.PostSQL object at 0x104c339a0>,), (<app.models.PostSQL object at 0x104c33910>,), (<app.models.PostSQL object at 0x104c33a90>,)]
    return post2
```

Content of <app.models.PostSQL object at 0x104c33a90> from post2:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glQVo.png)

Comment: @python_user edited post with adding all endpoint function and debugger data. Converted to POSTSQL data meaning that data have been converted to POSTSQL object (example post2, post3)

Comment: What is the question here? You have not asked any questions.

Comment: @python_user Thank you. The problem was in pycharm cache. The query didn't load extra data but it was saved earlier and load from cache . Sorry for wasting your time, but you really help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in pycharm/python cache. The query `query2 = select(PostSQL).options(load_only(PostSQL.id, PostSQL.title))` didn't load extra data but data from extra column have been saved earlier and load from cache.